# What are different way of writing controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs

1- Are there multiple ways of writing controllers using same version of AngularJS?
2- Is controller declaration is different for different versions of Angular?"

I have seen two ways of declaring controller so far. I do not know which one is better and why.

**1-**

```
myAppName.controller('categoryCtrl', function ($scope, categoryData) {
    $scope.menu = categoryData.all;
    $scope.menuTypes = {'Spotlight': false, 'All': true};

});
```

**2**

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.master = {};

  $scope.update = function(user) {
    $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
  };

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
  };
}
```

looking for explanation.

Comment: They are equivalent, but official developer guide recommends not to use global function syntax (the 2nd example).

Comment: Have you read ngController docs. Discuss namespace of registering with module , also I forget nuances but get different behaviors occasionaly depending on whther or not have simple  `ng-app` with no value or  ng-app="moduleName"

Answer (score 2):

### [ 1 ]

Lets say we have controller `myCtrl`:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.boo = 'boo';
}
```

So to print `$scope.boo` value we can write:

```
<div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
    <pre>{{boo}}</pre>
</div>
```

### [ 2 ]

However I can initiate controller like:

```
 function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.boo = 'boo';
 }

app.controller('booCntrl',myCtrl);
```

And print value in HTML:

```
<div ng-controller = "booCntrl">
    <pre>{{boo}}</pre>
</div>
```

Get the same result. Because I use `myCtrl` method  and put it as argument into  `app.controller`

### [ 3 ]

Third option:

```
app.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.boo = 'boo';
});
app.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

and print:

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
 <pre>fessCntrl: {{boo}}</pre>
</div>
```

As I know 1st option is good when you try to use dynamic controllers like in followed example: See Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/662/)**</kbd>. 3d option doesn't work here, we can't load controller by name from `app.controller`.

But I prefer 3d option in case of "root" controller just for code clearness. (1-2 options seem like simple methods).

*hope it helps*

Comment: 3rd example are you saying `{{boo}}` alone won't get compiled without the `controllerName:` prefix outside of the expression?

Comment: @charlietfl   I posted the demo, you welcome to find the way to call 3d option by name. Will be nice if you fins one

Comment: was legitimate question... was playing with demo though and when commented out `fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];` didn't see any behavior diff. I've never had to load controllers other than one time on page load....just being curious

Comment: @charlietfl I mean if you got object that contains controller name `fessCntrl`, and we want to use `ng-repeat` where each item is separate scope. Only 1st option works